# remove(Object obj) method of Vector misunderstand?

Tags: java, vector, collections

I have:

```
Vector vector=new Vector();
    vector.addElement("Nguyen");
    vector.addElement("Viet");
    vector.addElement("Jone");
    vector.addElement(28);
    vector.remove(28);
    System.out.println("Vector: "+ vector);
```

In Vector, i see two methods remove:

- public boolean remove(Object obj)
- public synchronized E remove(int index)

I just want to use public boolean remove(Object obj), but runtime occur a error. Someone can explain  to me that why? It seem wrong method of Vector?

Comment: What's the error? Why are you using `Vector`? Why not `ArrayList`?

Comment: Try using `vector.remove(Integer.valueOf(28));`. In either case, drop `Vector`, stick to `ArrayList` which is much faster, and better supported.

Comment: Use generics too. If you really want a `List` containing `Integer` and `String` values, at least declare it as `List<Object>` to make that intention clear.

Comment: In addition to `vector.remove(Integer.valueOf(28));`, `vector.remove((Integer) 28);` and `vector.remove((Object) 28);` both work.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: thanks to you, good explaination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer :**

There is no element at index position *28*. The `remove` method that you use takes an index position. To remove the element that has the value *28*, use `vector.remove(Integer.valueOf(28));`

**Long answer :**

A `Collection` in Java (such as a `Vector`) can only hold objects and not primitives. The `addElement` method in `Vector` takes an object parameter. When you say `vector.addElement(28)`, the primitive `int` value of *28* is boxed into an `Integer` object and then added to the `Vector`. The `remove` method on the other hand has an overloaded form that takes an `int` parameter so when you say `vector.remove(28)`, this version of the method is called which tries to remove the element at index position 28.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post the error, but I expect it would be `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, right?

OK, here's what's going on, `Vector` is old fashioned, long before Autoboxing, and Auto-unboxing was supported, in-turn adding a number to the vector required explicit `Integer` object creation. Removing *that* object element of-course also required the same. Since this is the story, the authors of the class, had no problem *overloading* 2 fully distinct methods with same name, since it was ***Radically Different*** (can't cast in any way back or forth, see Effective Java  p.194).

Now, in Java 5, autoboxing was introduced, but it wouldn't do so only if really required to do so. In your case, adding an element *must* autobox, since no alternative methods exists. In contrary, removing creates an ambiguity, so it will choose the *easier* one, the one that does not require autoboxing, resulting in calling the wrong method.

The solution would be to explicitly call the other method by manul boxing:

```
vector.remove(Integer.valueOf(28));
```

Answer (score 1):

`vector.remove(28)` attempts to remove the 29th element from the Vector (having index 28). Your Vector doesn't have that many elements, so you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

You should consider whether you really want your Vector to contain both `String`s and `Integer`s. That usually indicates a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

you must be getting below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 28
    at java.util.Vector.remove(Unknown Source)
    at TestInteger.main(TestInteger.java:14)
```

Exception is self explainatory. Reason is there is no element at index 28

see [vector remove with index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#remove(int)) but i believe you are looking for [remove object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#remove(java.lang.Object))